# Cumulative sum of a column of a multicolumn file and save the entire file

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

How to compute cumulative sum of a column in a multicolumn file and save the entire file using bash command?

An example of input file is below:

```
0       1869.75  31
1.342   1869.75  31
9.8     2479.45  177.8
74.15   3730.05  909.1 
43.6    5793.95  3562.95
```

I want that the left-most column would include cumulative sums from top to bottom, and the rest of the file remains the same.
The sample output file is below:

```
0        1869.75  31
1.342    1869.75  31
11.142   2479.45  177.8
85.292   3730.05  909.1 
128.892  5793.95  3562.95
```

I tried the following simple command on the file named "50.txt", but did nothing to the new file "n_50.txt":

```
awk '{sum+=$1;print}' 50.txt > n_50.txt
```

Thank you for your kind help in advance.

Comment: More details are required - at minimum: sample input, sample expected output, and what you have tried so far.   BTW, tasks like this are better done with awk or perl than with bash or sh code.

Comment: Honestly, this sounds like literally three very intuitive lines of code in python with pandas, why on earth do people try to do something like this on a shell? It's harder, slower, more error-prone and needs as much learning as learning how to do it in python

Comment: Anyway, you just gave us your assignment without any own attempt and without a precise question of your own - voting to close as too broad

Comment: your (not-yet-approved) anonymous edit is a step in the right direction, but [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: This is my first post here. Thank you @cas for instructing me post the question in proper way.

Comment: @Marcus Müller I agree with you. I know to take the cumulative summing using cumsum option of nympy in python. But don't how to save the file or edit in the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
# cat q
0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
                                                                                                                       

# awk '{sum+=$1;$1=sum}1' q
0 1 2
1 2 3
3 3 4
6 4 5
```

The idea is to replace first field with the value of `sum`

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

you need to update `$1`'s value

try

```
awk '{sum+=$1;$1=sum;print} ' 50.txt > n_50.txt
```

(I didn't test as I can't copy/paste images)

Comment: Will work. There are probably few versions of `awk` where I have my doubts, Solaris default `awk` for example :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov The default awk on Solaris is old, broken awk where almost nothing works and there are 2 other functional awks on Solaris so you never have to consider old, broken awk when posting answers as no-one should ever use it. This will work in any awk worth mentioning (and FWIW I expect it would even work in old, broken awk).

Comment: @EdMorton, unfortunately in PATH by default you will see this old version. and good amount of users may use it....

Comment: I know it's the default awk (as I mentioned) and so everyone who wants to use awk must change their PATH to not use it and use `/usr/xpg[46]/bin/awk` instead or spend the rest of their life wondering why 90% of the scripts they write just output `syntax error at line 1` and most of the remaining 10% produce unexpected output. Or `nawk` but it's further from POSIX compliant than the xpg awks.

Comment: Thank you so much @Archemar it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (`mlr`):

```bash
$ cat file
1.1 2 3
4.4 5 6
5.5 6 7
8.8 9 0
```

```bash
$ mlr --nidx put '@sum += $1; $1 = @sum' file
1.100000 2 3
5.500000 5 6
11.000000 6 7
19.800000 9 0
```

```bash
$ mlr --nidx put '@sum += $1; $1 = fmtnum(@sum,"%lg")' file
1.1 2 3
5.5 5 6
11 6 7
19.8 9 0
```

Comment: Thank you @Kusalananda for replying me. I don't have mlr command, so I could not try it.

Comment: @AtikulHaqueFarazi This is why you have a package manager. Miller can also be run directly via a Docker container or a Conda environment.